# Find the geo coordinates in reference to the zip codes and store them in a new array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps

I have an array of zip codes which looks like this:

```
zipcode_primary = [
      {
        name: 'New York Location 1', 
        zip_code: 10001
      },
      {
        name: 'New York Location 2', 
        zip_code: 10005
      },
      {
        name: 'New York Location 3', 
        zip_code: 10020
      }
    ]
```

I am trying to put those locations on a google map as markers. But to my understanding I would have to retrieve the geo coordinates (latitude and longitudes) in order to place markers on the map. So probably the array would look something like this?

```
zipcode_primary_updated = [
  {
    name: 'New York Location 1', 
    zip_code: 10001,
    xcord: -73.9, 
    ycord: 40.7
  },
  {
    name: 'New York Location 2', 
    zip_code: 10005,
    xcord: -74.0, 
    ycord: 40.7
  },
  {
    name: 'New York Location 3', 
    zip_code: 10020,
    xcord: -73.9800, 
    ycord: 40.7594
  }
]
```

My question would be how would I find the geo coordinates in reference to the zip codes and store them in a new array.

I have looked into some previously asked questions but didn't really find something that I could use. I found out that it can be done.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Also: when using Google's Geocoding API, follow their advice and [store the coordinates somewhere instead of looking them up every time](http://leavesofcode.net/2013/05/07/caching-google-maps-geocoding-lookups/). You have a limit on how many times their Geocoding API can be accessed in a single day, and it's easier to hit than you think.

Comment: @Blazemonger--that makes sense. I think I would make more sense to create an array of those coordinates because these are store locations. So those wont really change that fast. But it makes sense what you are saying. thanks for sharing this